# Database Design for Questions and Answers

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm building a website that will host a variety of questionnaires. Each questionnaire has a different number of questions and each question has a different number of answers. I have attempted to design a database to hold the questions and possible answers for each questionnaire, but I end up having separate tables for each question. Is this correct or am I going wrong somewhere?

For example

```
Table for question x

  Answer  | Answer ID
       1         019
       2         089
```

I cant have a fixed size table for all questions as I don't have a maximum amount of answers. This obviously means I could end up with hundreds of tables, one for each question.

Comment: You may find some ideas from similar question, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/how-to-keep-long-multiple-of-questions-and-answers-in-database/9346#9346

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have an application at our workplace that does a similar thing. It works by having a table that contains a list of all possible questions like such:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTIONS
(
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   SUMMARY NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(255) NULL
);
```

Then you have an ANSWERS and a QUESTIONAIRES table defined using the same structure above. Once you have these two tables you then define a table to hold the list of question/answer possibilties as such:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION_ANSWERS
(
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   QUESTION INT NOT NULL REFERENCES QUESTIONS(ID),
   ANSWER INT NOT NULL REFERENCES ANSWERS(ID)
);
```

Once you have these you can then create a table to contain the responses as such:

```
CREATE TABLE RESPONSES
(
   QUESTIONAIRE INT NOT NULL REFERENCES QUESTIONAIRES(ID),
   RESPONSE INT NOT NULL REFERENCES QUESTION_ANSWERS(ID)
);
```

This will give you maximum flexibility allowing you to add new questions and answers without having to change your database design frequently. It can get a bit complicated if you need to version the questions/answers but this should give you a good foothold to work from.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you saying that the QUESTION_ANSWERS table will have multiple QUESTION(ID)s for different ANSWERS(id). I.e repetition of the same QUESTION(id)s, if one question had 5 possible answers you would have 5 instances of the QUESTION(id)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You probably need one more table to hold the list of responders (maybe with name, contact details, dates, etc), and then a extra field in the RESPONSES table to act as a foreign key to this table. This way you can get the responses per responder.

Answer (score -3):

#### QUESTIONNAIRE

```
QUESTIONNAIRE_ID (PK),
QUESTIONARIE_TITLE
```

#### QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS

```
QUESTIONARIE_QUESTIONS_ID (PK),
QUESTIONARIE_QUESTIONS,
QUESTIONNAIRE_ID (PK)
```

#### ANSWERS

```
ANSWER_ID (PK),
QUESTIONARIE_QUESTIONS_ID (FK)
```